# How to animate movement with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have code that moves a circle around the screen. My goal is to reduce the amount of code with css animation. But I don't understand how to do it. There is a problem that I cannot solve if I use css animation. The circle goes beyond the screen, although I have code to prevent this. Help please

I have JS code as well as html and css. Also, my js code helps with opening the popup.

```js
let elem = document.querySelector('.button');

function check() {
  const popup = document.getElementsByClassName('popup');
  if (document.getElementById('popup__input').checked = true) {
    for (var i = 0; i < popup.length; i += 1) {
      popup[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
  } else {
    popup.style.display = "none";
  }
}

const changePosition = () => {
  let randX = Math.random();
  let randY = Math.random();
  const circleSize = {
    width: elem.clientWidth,
    heigth: elem.clientHeight
  };

  const windowWidth = window.innerWidth - circleSize.width;
  const windowheigth = window.innerHeight - circleSize.heigth;

  let randXMult = windowheigth * randX;
  let randXP = randXMult + 'px';
  let randYMult = windowWidth * randY;
  let randYP = randYMult + 'px';


  elem.style.top = randXP;
  elem.style.left = randYP;
};

setInterval(changePosition, 1000);
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
  position: absolute;
  transition: linear 4s;
}

input[type=text],
select {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 758px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 40px 0;
  font-size: 60px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.form__input {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 45px;
  padding-right: 45px;
}

.close__button {
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: start;
  height: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgb(208, 201, 201);
}

.form__button {
  width: 550px;
  height: 55px;
  margin-top: 110px;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.overlay {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.popup {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 850px;
  height: 200px;
  background: rgb(208, 201, 201);
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: end;
}

.popup__check {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 3;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}

@media (max-width: 1024.98px) {
  .button {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
    position: absolute;
    transition: linear 4s;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 890px) {
  .popup {
    width: 750px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768.98px) {
  input[type=text],
  select {
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 50px 0;
    font-size: 40px;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .form__button {
    width: 350px;
    height: 45px;
    margin-top: 105px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .popup {
    width: 600px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 620.98px) {
  .popup {
    width: 480px;
  }
  input[type=text],
  select {
    width: 395px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 50px 0;
    font-size: 40px;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .close__button {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  .form__input {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
  }
  form {
    margin-left: 10%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 507.98px) {
  input[type=text],
  select {
    width: 280px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 45px 0;
    font-size: 25px;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .form__button {
    width: 240px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: 95px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .popup {
    width: 360px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400.98px) {
  input[type=text],
  select {
    width: 290px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 35px 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .form__button {
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .popup {
    width: 360px;
    height: 150px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 358.98px) {
  input[type=text],
  select {
    width: 230px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 35px 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .form__button {
    width: 180px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .popup {
    width: 290px;
    height: 150px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 300.98px) {
  input[type=text],
  select {
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 35px 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .form__button {
    width: 140px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .popup {
    width: 255px;
    height: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="button">
    <input onclick="check()" type="checkbox" name="popup__input" id="popup__input" class="popup__check">
  </div>
  <div class="popup" name="popup" id="popup">
    <label class="popup__label">
            <form>
                <div class="form__input">
                    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
                </div>
                <div class="close-button__container">
                    <button class="close__button">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <button class="form__button" type="submit" form="nameform" value="Submit">Відправити</button>
            </form>
        </label>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay">
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: You can't randomize values in pure CSS... Also, your question contains way too much code, I'd suggest removing everything that's unrelated to the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Since @Cerbus wrote, there is no way to generate random numbers with CSS. Only SCSS can create a random number on the initial build of the CSS file. You could write a keyframe animation in CSS with many steps and random positions.

You could generate these steps with JS :).